# Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables in WinForms

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am working in VB.NET Windows application

In my load event I am giving code like this for loading data from different table to my `DataGridView`.

For that I use code like this:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select M.Model,c.Colname,ma.Make from Model_tbl M join Color_tbl C on c.colid=M.mdlid join Make_tbl ma on ma.mkid=c.colid  where mdlid=5", con.connect)
        Dim builder As SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "MyTable")
        If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then
            DGV.DataSource = ds.Tables("MyTable")

        End If
```

When clicking update button I want to update data to different tables from my `DataGridView`. So I wrote code like this in my update button event.

```
 Me.Validate()
        Me.da.Update(Me.ds.Tables("MyTable"))
        Me.ds.AcceptChanges()
```

but on this line

```
Me.da.Update(Me.ds.Tables("MyTable"))
```

I get an error:

> Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

`SqlCommandBuilder` cannot generate the UPDATE/INSERT statements required for the DataAdapter update command when the SELECT command contains JOINS between two or more tables.

On MSDN you can read

> SqlCommandBuilder automatically generates `single-table commands` that
>   are used to reconcile changes made to a DataSet with the associated
>   SQL Server database.

The workaround is to provide by yourself the commands for the properties

```
SqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand 
SqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand 
SqlDataAdapter.DeleteCommand
```

Comment: while i am giving this showing:Property access must assign to the property or use its value.