# Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqldataadapter

The issue is that after I use my stored procedure below I try to use an update command to update the data, that is where I get the

> Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.

I have narrowed it down where its the join statement in my code below that is giving me the issue but I am unsure of how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
USE [MSW]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Get_CSF_Transactions_MTPT]    Script Date: 10/22/2020 3:08:59 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Get_CSF_Transactions_MTPT]

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT  DISTINCT  EOD_CSF_Archive.ID, EOD_CSF_Archive.RecID, EOD_CSF_Archive.mercid, EOD_CSF_Archive.termid, EOD_CSF_Archive.proccode, EOD_CSF_Archive.trandt, EOD_CSF_Archive.trantm, EOD_CSF_Archive.pan, EOD_CSF_Archive.tranamt, EOD_CSF_Archive.trandbcr, EOD_CSF_Archive.tranrc, EOD_CSF_Archive.merccurr, EOD_CSF_Archive.customer, EOD_CSF_Archive.wkiv,
                      EOD_CSF_Archive.Merc_Settled, EOD_CSF_Archive.Proc_Date_Merc_Settled, EOD_CSF_Archive.DataWarehouse, EOD_CSF_Archive.DataWarehouseDate, EOD_CSF_Archive.TransactionIdentifier, EOD_CSF_Archive.network, EOD_CSF_Archive.ProdDesc, EOD_CSF_Archive.tranauth, EOD_CSF_Archive.transeq, EOD_Mr_Payments.AccountNumber
    FROM         EOD_CSF_Archive
    JOIN EOD_Mr_Payments on EOD_CSF_Archive.EntryID = EOD_Mr_Payments.EntryID
    WHERE  (EOD_CSF_Archive.DataWarehouse = 0 OR EOD_CSF_Archive.DataWarehouse IS NULL) and Merc_Settled = 1
    ORDER BY mercid, termid
END
```

Here is my code in C#:

```
public void Build_MTPT_File()
{
    string fname = string.Format("{0}_{1}.INT", "MTPT", Proc_Date_YYYYMMDD);
    LogToFile.WriteLog(string.Format("Building: {0}", fname));
    string fpath = string.Format("{0}{1}", ArcDir, fname);

    ExcryptProvider exp = new ExcryptProvider(true);

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(AppSettings.MSWConnString))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        
        using (SqlDataAdapter daReproc = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_Get_CSF_Transactions_MTPT", cn))
        {
            
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(daReproc);
            daReproc.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 1000;
            daReproc.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            daReproc.Fill(dt);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                var ProdDesc1 = row["ProdDesc"].ToString();
                var ProdDesc2 = ProdDesc1.Split('-');
                var OnUs = "O";
                var NotOnUs = "N";
                var EmptyRow = new string(' ', 5);

                sb.Append(row["MercID"].ToString().Trim().PadRight(15, ' '));
                sb.Append(row["MercID"].ToString().Trim().PadRight(15, ' '));
                sb.Append(row["TermID"].ToString().Trim().PadRight(8, ' '));
                sb.Append(row["proccode"].ToString().Trim().PadLeft(6, '0'));
                sb.Append(row["tranDbCr"].ToString().Trim().PadRight(1, ' '));
                sb.Append(row["MERCCURR"].ToString().Trim().PadLeft(3, '0'));
                sb.Append(row["tranamt"].ToString().Trim().PadLeft(15, '0'));
                try
                {
                    sb.Append(Convert.ToDateTime(row["Proc_Date_Merc_Settled"]).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
                }
                catch
                {
                    sb.Append("00000000");
                }
                sb.Append(row["trandt"].ToString().Trim().PadLeft(8, ' '));
                sb.Append(row["trantm"].ToString().Trim().PadLeft(6, ' '));
                //LogToFile.WriteLog(row["id"].ToString().Trim());
                string tmppan = exp.DecryptASCIICBC(AppSettings.DEK, row["wkiv"].ToString().Trim(), row["customer"].ToString().Trim());
                if (tmppan.Length >= 9)
                {
                    sb.Append(tmppan.Trim().Substring(0, 9).PadRight(19, ' '));
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(new string(' ', 19));
                }

                sb.Append(row["TransactionIdentifier"].ToString().Trim().PadRight(15, ' '));

                if (ProdDesc2.Length > 1)
                {
                    sb.Append(ProdDesc2[0].ToString().Trim().PadRight(15, ' '));
                    sb.Append(OnUs.ToString().Trim().PadRight(2, ' '));

                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(ProdDesc1.ToString().Trim().PadRight(15, ' '));
                    sb.Append(NotOnUs.ToString().Trim().PadRight(2, ' '));
                }
                sb.Append(row["tranauth"].ToString().Trim().PadRight(6, ' '));
                sb.Append(row["transeq"].ToString().Trim().PadRight(6, ' '));
                sb.Append(row["AccountNumber"].ToString().Trim().PadRight(16, ' '));

                sb.Append("\r\n");
                row["DataWarehouse"] = 1;
                row["DataWarehouseDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
            }
            WriteFile(fpath, sb.ToString());
            daReproc.Update(dt);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So... what is your question? Your title and SP code don't on the face of it have anything to do with each other.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @DaleK sorry about that. The issue is that after I use my stored procedure I try to use an update command to update the data that is where I get the "Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables ". I have narrowed it down where its the join statement above that is giving me the issue but I am unsure of how to fix it.

Comment: [Edit] any updates directly into your question. And show us your update command and it fits together. We can't magically read your code!

Comment: Don't you need to supply the `UpdateCommand`? Your SP is only a select command, its not going to update.

Comment: @DaleK the update command I am talking about is daReproc.Update(dt); at the end of the c# code. That is where my error is occurring. Unless I am mistaken that is a basic update command for datatable in C#. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: No that is the `update` method. Your DataAdaptor has a `daReproc.SelectCommand` which you are setting, it also has a [`daReproc.UpdateCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), which you are not setting.

Comment: @DaleK sorry about that. Its breaking on my update method not an update command and that is where the issue is occurring.  The code never had an update command before. All I have done is added more fields to pull from the stored procedure by editing it and adding a join.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vb.net Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728372/vb-net-dynamic-sql-generation-is-not-supported-against-multiple-base-tables-in-w)